# React js - produce actions after a Post method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am developing a React application with Axios, ExpressJS, and MySQL. I want to redirect the user after sending the data to the database. Currently, the data is correct on the database, but the redirect, confirmation toast, and email send are not happening. The console.log (response); returns nothing. How to trigger actions?

I tried not putting a .then() response but it didn't change anything

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";
import { Toast } from "bootstrap";
import {useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:9999",
});

export default function AddStructure() {
  const [assetReg, setAssetReg] = useState("");
  const [structureNameReg, setStructureNameReg] = useState("");
  const [emailReg, setEmailReg] = useState("");
  const [townReg, setTownReg] = useState("");
  const [informationReg, setInformationReg] = useState("");
  const [numberStructuresReg, setNumberStructuresReg] = useState("");
  const [newsletterReg, setNewsletterReg] = useState("");
  const [manageScheduleReg, setManageScheduleReg] = useState("");
  const [flyerReg, setFlyerReg] = useState("");
  const [drinksReg, setDrinksReg] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const config = {
    SecureToken: "39ced67b-1fcc-48a2-8d18-48e5d1dc9ad8",
    To: "sport.admin@yopmail.com",
    From: emailReg,
    Subject: "confirmation creation of your structure",
    Body: `Dear partner, we are pleased to confirm the creation of your structure. ${structureNameReg}  glass.`,
  };

  const AddStructure = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!assetReg || !structureNameReg || !emailReg || !townReg) {
      Toast.error(
        "please provide value into asset, structure name , email and town"
      );
    } else {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
      client
        .post("/addStructure", {
          asset: assetReg,
          structure_name: structureNameReg,
          email: emailReg,
          town: townReg,
          information: informationReg,
          number_structure: numberStructuresReg,
          newsletter: newsletterReg,
          manage_schedule: manageScheduleReg,
          flyer: flyerReg,
          drinks: drinksReg,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          Toast.success("Structure added Successfully");
          if (window.email) {
            window.email.send(config);
          }
          setTimeout(() => navigate("/"), 500);
        })
        .then.catch((err) => Toast.error(err.response.data));
    }
  };
```

Comment: what is .then.catch ? , can you just put catch and see if the code in the catch block is being executed

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick response. Indeed with your proposal, I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: bootstrap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Toast.error is not a function. I'm looking at the Bootstrap documentation to correct this one. thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is no function call in your AddStructure component, Other than it didn't have a dom elements in your components return.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).